# Count if cells have the same month and year in their date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a filter using a command like countif or similar with the following Criteria. I do not know if it possible and if it is this task is beyond my current knowledge of Excel; I have been unable to create a code that even makes sense with formulas such as Countif.

This is an example of the table that is going to use the formula:

[image: Table]

In the cell belonging to Each Sample (e.i, 1) A value need to appear if there is a sample with the same code which date has similar month and year. later I will use this value to filter all Samples with similar Month and Year.

I deeply appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED),

```
=countifs(a:a, a2, c:c, ">=" & date(year(c2), month(c2), 1), c:c, "<" & date(year(c2), month(c2) + 1, 1))
```

This may be the [función CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Funci%C3%B3n-CONTAR-SI-CONJUNTO-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842) for your regional settings. Your computer may also be using a semi-colon (e.g. `;`) instead of the EN-US comma as a list separator.